# Android: GPS provider is never chosen. Only network providers are present

Tags: android, networking, gps, provider

I'm trying to make my app choose the GPS provider. Method getBestProvider() yields the network provider and method getAllProviders() yields three network providers as well. 
Strange thing is that the GPS is enabled in my Samsung GTS5360 device, which is also proven by the isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) call. I'm using Android 2.3.6.

My manifest file has both permissions (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION). I have also implemented a GpsStatus listener which I added to my locationManager object to listen to GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS events, but so far nothing is happening.

When I run other embedded GPS applications, GPS works. I have clear sky conditions, sitting on my balcony.

Any suggestions on what is might happening is more than welcome. I can post my code if necessary.

Comment: "getAllProviders() yields three network providers as well" -- there is only one `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. What makes you think that you are getting the string `"NETWORK_PROVIDER"` three times in the returned `List<String>` from `getAllProviders()`?

Comment: You are so correct. The for-loop in getAllProviders() returns 0) network, 1) passive and 2) gps. My bad!

Comment: With respect to `getBestProvider()`, something in your `Criteria` is causing GPS to not be a valid choice, I guess.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for your help!!! By adjusting my criteria, especially by setting ACCURACY_FINE and POWER_LOW I made the GPS provider work like a charm... Again thank you! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommonsWare provided the solution to my problem. By setting the correct criteria, ACCURACY_FINE and POWER_LOW, the GPS provider became the provider of choice. Kudos to CommonsWare!